# How To make relocatable rpm?

Tags: java, maven, rpm

I have java application with pom.xml. I am making rpm package with prefixes tags .

When I am querying on prefix tags of rpm :

```
sudo rpm -qp --queryformat "%{prefixes}\n" java-hbase-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT20160330060627.noarch.rpm
```

I got  ==> /var

IF I run following command :

```
rpm -qi java-hbase-processor | grep Relocations
```

I got :
Relocations : /opt /tmp 
Relocations : /var /tmp

All above shows that rpm is relocatable . But if run install command

```
sudo rpm -i --prefix=/home/sohanvir/ java-hbase-processor-1.0-SNAPSHOT20160330060627.noarch.rpm
```

It will give error with message:

**error: package java-hbase-processor is not relocatable**

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you need to extract only some files ?

Answer (score 5):

According to [RPM.org](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/relocatable.html):

> By default, RPM will install a relocatable package in the prefix directory listed in the spec file. You can override this on the RPM install command line with *"--prefix `<dir>`"*. For example, if the package in question were going to be installed in "/opt" but you don't have enough disk space there (and it is a relocatable package), you could install it *"--prefix /usr/opt"*.
>
> If there is more then one Prefix you may relocate each prefix separately by using syntax like:
>
> `rpm ... --relocate /opt=/usr/opt --relocate /etc=/usr/etc ...`
>
> If any of the Prefixes is not being relocated they can be skipped on the command line

However, it goes on to say that there are a number of things that can go wrong in building a relocatable RPM (even if you see the `Prefix` tags).  If you only want to extract files from the RPM, there are tools for that (such as [`rpmunpack`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rpmunpack/), [`rpm2cpio`](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-rpm2cpio.html) or `unrpm`).

Further reading:

- [Explain: Red Hat Linux RPM Relocatable and Not Relocatable Packages](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rpm-relocatable-packages/)
- [RPM spec made relocatable by adding prefix but while installing i do not see the files installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755810/rpm-spec-made-relocatable-by-adding-prefix-but-while-installing-i-do-not-see-the)
- [Chapter 15. Making a Relocatable Package](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-reloc.html)

  > A relocatable package is a package that is standard in every way, save one. The difference lies in the prefix tag. When this tag is added to a spec file, RPM will attempt to build a relocatable package.
  >
  > Note the word "attempt". There are a few conditions that must be met before a relocatable package can be built successfully, and this chapter will cover them all. But first, let's look at exactly how RPM can relocate a package. And the one component at the heart of package relocation is the prefix tag.
- [HowTo: Extract an RPM Package Files Without Installing It](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-extract-an-rpm-package-without-installing-it.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Its really useful . Finally i was able to relocate using sudo rpm --install --relocate <prefix>=<new path> <package name>